# Bootstrap 3.3.4 single image not showing under 768 pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in the very final stretch of making a site fully responsive except for this one issue. I have a header with a background video and a div with an `img` element inside this div. Everything scales great until the screen resolution reaches less than 768 pixels wide then the `img` is set to visibility: hidden, according to Developer Tools in Chrome.

I have attempted making a class and setting `display: inline !important`, using jQuery to offer different images per resolution as well as trying various media queries in hopes of handling this. I have also attempted using another image, which is visible further down the page, in place of the required image and still no dice. I'm at a loss and come to you fine people for assistance.

Site is built with Bootstrap 3.3.4 with Animate.css (https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and WOW.js (http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/). I can offer a URL to the site as well.

Here's my viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Here's the header:

```
<header id="first">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="img/icon_logo.png" id="logo" class="wow flipInX img-responsive col-xs-12" alt="Find and meet friends wherever you roam." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <video autoplay="" loop="" class="fillWidth fadeIn wow collapse in" data-wow-delay="0.5s" poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/coverr/poster/Traffic-blurred2.jpg" id="video-background">
        <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/coverr/mp4/Traffic-blurred2.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</header>
```

I've even tried taking out the class attribute (including each class within the attribute) to no avail. If I need to include more code for you, I can do so as well. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: add the link to your site. In general when using wow i try to avoid adding the effect to the element itself and instead add it to its containing element, eg div, section, span, etc.

Comment: Can you post your CSS code of the class you are using please.

Comment: Can you create a snippet, bin or fiddle so we could see the problem a live?

Comment: Alright, here's a link to the site: http://www.enyi.us/tobh/site

@partypete25 so instead of applying wow to the `img` element, apply it to the "inner" div instead? Or should I go even further with it and apply it to the header since both elements inside the header use it? This is my first go with wow, used to do all this manually.

@Alex here's a pastebin with the various classes in use at this section: http://pastebin.ca/3332085

@MoshFeu the link is at the top of this comment.

Thanks gentlemen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed when looking at the website that the image is on the page (in a narrow view <768px ) but it is off the screen (far down) due to it's `fixed` positioning and massive top and bottom padding.

When the browser is greater than 768px wide, some new css is added in a media query that positions the image in the correct spot. Once it is in this position, the wow js works because it is in view and updates it's visiblity to visible.

Try adding this to your main.css line ~369:

```
header .header-content {
    padding: 0em 5em;
    top: 50%;
}
```

You can adjust this as you like. the wow js plugin sets visibility to hidden because the image is so far down on the screen that you haven't scrolled it into view yet. Hopefully if you can position it correctly the plugin will work as expected.

Comment: You're a god amongst men. Thank you so much! This had me stumped! I thought it might be getting pushed down below one of the div's but with the visibility going to hidden I was completely stumped. That fixed it.